# Check or Uncheck Checkbox based on Textbox value Adobe Acrobat Stamp Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat, pdfstamper

It is for Adobe Acrobat Javascript:

I'm trying this code but failed for two days. I'm trying to put this code in textField Calculate Tab and in Custom Calculation Script.

Any help will be appreciated.

And let me also tell you what I'm trying to achieve.
I want that if user put any value in textField it check the value if it is "Yes" it should mark the check box Checked. and if it is No it will do nothing or uncheck the checkbox.

```
var subText= "Subcontractor Yes or No";
var cTitle = "Document Data for Stamp";

if(event.source.forReal && (event.source.stampName =="#New123"))
{
event.value = app.response(subText , cTitle);

if(this.getField("subtext").value =="Yes")
{
this.getField("SubCheckbox").value="On";
}

if(this.getField("subtext").value =="No")
{
this.getField("Subcheckbox").value="Off";
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please add your HTML as well?

Comment: its not html its for Adobe Acrobat Field and checkbox

Comment: What action are you attaching this JavaScript to? Also, consider using the Field checkThisBox method rather than setting the export values.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it worked for me perfectly.

```
var subText= "Subcontractor Yes or No";
var cTitle = "Document Data for Stamp";

if(event.source.forReal && (event.source.stampName =="#New123"))
{
event.value = app.response(subText , cTitle);

if(this.event.value =="Yes")
{
this.getField("Subcheckbox").value="On";
}

if(this.event.value =="No")
{
this.getField("Subcheckbox").value="Off";
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should try something like this in the onchange function of your textbox

```
function myScript() {
    var text = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
if(text == "Yes")
    document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;
else
    document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = false;
}
```

Comment: I clearly mentioned above its not HTML javascript it is for Adobe Acrobat